# How to read a file when it is changed, in batch

Tags: batch-file

I have an exe application which writes the output in a txt file. I want to print this output in terminal, in the same time in which it is written by the application.

Comment: Try looking at solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632/how-to-monitor-a-text-file-in-realtime

Comment: I see only GUI and PowerShell solutions. I need to make this in a bat file.

Comment: There's a Unix utility called `tee` that will let you write to the console and a file at the same time.  [Here's a .bat solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719322/1683264) that emulates this.